# How can I restart my app when it is clicked on from the recents menu instead of resuming?

Tags: android, android-lifecycle, oncreate, onresume

I am making a game, and I want my app to restart when it is selected in the recents menu. So if mid-game, the player presses the home button the app would open fresh again. I tried this earlier but to no avail.

```
@Override
public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();

}

@Override
public void onPause(){
    super.onPause();
    onStop();
    onDestroy();
}
```

What do I put in the onResume() method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recomend you to do nothing special `onPause()` because at that callback activity could be still visible to the user and it could be confusing, [see docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html).

Instead of this try to use `onStop()`:

```
@Override
protected  void onStop(){
    super.onStop();
    finish();
}
```

Also you can try to recreate your game objects when user navigates back to the game on `onRestart()` of your activity.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public void onPause(){
    super.onPause();
    finish();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not a ideal solution but you can always kill the process id of the application on that activity, where you want to start the app from the beginning,

but this will destroy your current progress in the game so you might want to handle that before you call this line of code

```
 android.os.Process.killProcess(Process.myPid());
```

call this in your onStop() callback of your activity